# What's the idiomatic way to define multiple functions as the same type in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, idioms

I am an experienced programmer in ruby, python and javascript (specifically back-end node.js), I have worked in java, perl and c++, and I've used lisp and haskell academically, but I'm brand new to Scala and trying to learn some conventions.

I have a function that accepts a function as a parameter, similar to how a sort function accepts a comparator function. What is the more idiomatic way of implementing this?

Suppose this is the function that accepts a function parameter y:

```
object SomeMath {
  def apply(x: Int, y: IntMath): Int = y(x)
}
```

Should `IntMath` be defined as a `trait` and different implementations of `IntMath` defined in different objects? (let's call this option A)

```
trait IntMath {
   def apply(x: Int): Int
}

object AddOne extends IntMath {
   def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 1
}

object AddTwo extends IntMath {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 2
}

AddOne(1)
// => 2
AddTwo(1)
// => 3
SomeMath(1, AddOne)
// => 2
SomeMath(1, AddTwo)
// => 3
```

Or should `IntMath` be a type alias for a function signature? (option B)

```
type IntMath = Int => Int

object Add {
  def one: IntMath = _ + 1
  def two: IntMath = _ + 2
}

Add.one(1)
// => 2
Add.two(1)
// => 3
SomeMath(1, Add.one)
// => 2
SomeMath(1, Add.two)
// => 3
```

but which one is more idiomatic scala?

Or are neither idiomatic? (option C)

My previous experiences in functional languages leans me towards B, but I have never seen that before in scala. On the other hand, though the `trait` seems to add unnecessary clutter, I have seen that implementation and it seems to work much more smoothly in Scala (since the object becomes callable with the `apply` function).

[**Update**] Fixed the examples code where an `IntMath` type is passed into `SomeMath`. The syntatic sugar that scala provides where an `object` with an `apply` method becomes callable like a function gives the illusion that `AddOne` and `AddTwo` are functions and passed like functions in Option A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Scala has explicit function types, I'd say that if you need to pass a function to your function, use the function type, i.e. your option B. They are explicitly there for this purpose.

It is not exactly clear what do you mean by saying that you "have never seen that before in scala", BTW. A lot of standard library methods accept functions as their parameters, for example, collection transformation methods. Creating type aliases to convey semantics of a more complex type is perfectly idiomatic Scala as well, and it does not really matter whether the aliased type is a function or not. For example, one of the core types in my current project is actually a type alias to a function, which conveys the semantics using a descriptive name and also allows to easily pass conforming functions without a necessity to explicitly create a subclass of some trait.

It is also important, I believe, to understand that syntax sugar of the `apply` method does not really have anything to do with how functions or functional traits are used. Indeed, `apply` methods do have this ability to be invoked just with parentheses; however, it does not mean that different types having an `apply` method, even with the same signature, are *interoperable*, and I think that this interoperability is what matters in this situation, as well as an ability to easily construct instances of such types. After all, in your specific example it only matters for *your* code whether you could use the syntax sugar on `IntMath` or not, but for users of your code an ability to easily construct an instance of `IntMath`, as well as an ability to pass some existing thing they already have as `IntMath`, is much more important.

With the `FunctionN` types, you have the benefit of being able to use the anonymous function syntax to construct instances of these types (actually, several syntaxes, at least these: `x => y`, `{ x => y }`, `_.x`, `method _`, `method(_)`). There even was no way to create instances of "Single Abstract Method" types before Scala 2.11, and even there it requires a compiler flag to actually enable this feature. This means that the users of your type will have to write either this:

```
SomeMath(10, _ + 1)
```

or this:

```
SomeMath(10, new IntMath {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 1
})
```

Naturally, the former approach is much clearer.

Additionally, `FunctionN` types provide a single common denominator of functional types, which improves interoperability. Functions in math, for example, do not have any kind of "type" except their signature, and you can use any function in place of any other function, as long as their signatures match. This property is beneficial in programming too, because it allows reusing definitions you already have for different purposes, reducing the number of conversions and therefore potential mistakes that you might do when writing these conversions.

Finally, there are indeed situations where you would want to create a separate type for your function-like interface. One example is that with full-fledged types, you have an ability to define a companion object, and companion objects participate in implicits resolution. This means that if instances of your function type are supposed to be provided implicitly, then you can take advantage of having a companion object and define some common implicits there, which would make them available for all users of the type without additional imports:

```
// You might even want to extend the function type
// to improve interoperability
trait Converter[S, T] extends (S => T) {
  def apply(source: S): T
}

object Converter {
  implicit val intToStringConverter: Converter[Int, String] = new Converter[Int, String] {
    def apply(source: Int): String = source.toString
  }
}
```

Here having a piece of implicit scope associated with the type is useful, because otherwise users of `Converter` would need to always import contents of some object/package to obtain default implicit definitions; with this approach, however, all implicits defined in `object Converter` will be searched by default.

However, these situations are not very common. As a general rule, I think, you should first try to use the regular function type. If you find that you *do* need a separate type, for a practical reason, only then you should create your own type.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! To clarify what I meant by "have never seen that before in scala", I mean that though I have seen type aliases for complex map, seq, etc. types, I have not seen any libraries that type alias a function type and then define functions as that type.

Comment: @skyxie, just take a look at the standard collections method `map`. It is a generic method with two generic types `A` coming from the collection and `B` specific for the method and it accepts `f: A => B` which is a function from type `A` onto type `B`. And the arity is not limited to 1, `(Int, Double) => String` is a function with two parameters: `Int` and `Double` and `String` as the result type. Using type alias for such a thing it not a common way because the natural way to write the type is already very short.

Comment: In that case, are there also cases in the standard library where objects extend traits and are passed like functions? 

The syntatic sugar that scala provides such that an `object` with an `apply` function appears like a top-level namespace function looks intended for that purpose. I have updated my original question to show what that looks like.

Or is having an `object` extend a `trait` unusual?

Comment: As for libraries, I think Akka provides a good example: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Actor$.html#Receive=PartialFunction[Any,Unit] . It is an alias for `PartialFunction` not `Function1`, but still it demonstrates that such aliases are useful (and `PartialFunction`s in Scala also enjoy a different status from other traits).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is not to define anything and keep the function type explicit:

```
def apply(x: Int, y: Int => Int): Int = y(x)
```

This makes the code more readable by making it clear which arguments are data objects and which are function objects. (Purists will say that there is no distinction in a functional language, but I think this is a useful distinction in most real-world code, especially if you come from a more declarative background)

If the arguments or results become more complicated then they can be defined as their own types, but the function itself remains explicit:

```
def apply(x: MyValue, y: MyValue => MyValue2): MyValue2 = y(x)
```

Failing that, `B` is preferable because it allows you to pass functions as lambdas:

```
SomeMath(1, _ + 3)
```

`A` would require you to declare a new instance of `IntMath` which is more cumbersome and less idiomatic.